# Jquery to make div appear after scroll is showing on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I input this code to make a small logo appear as the user scrolls past the navigation bar which works perfectly (see: http://wmlgatto.blogspot.co.uk/), although the logo appears when you load the page.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y &gt; 140) {
    $(&#39;.stickylogo&#39;).fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(&#39;.stickylogo&#39;).fadeOut();
  }
});

</script>
```

I tried setting .stickylogo {display:none;} and this doesn't seem to fix the problem.

How do I make sure the div doesn't appear when the page loads? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
.stickylogo {
    display: none !important;
}
```

the css applied on #navigationbar li is setting the display to inline.

and change the scroll function like this.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 140) {
    $(".stickylogo").attr("style", "display: inline !important");
    $(".stickylogo").fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(".stickylogo").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but with !important, it doesn't show at all even when you scroll

Comment: @gattocat did you also change the scroll function ??i added one line before fadein is called

Comment: @gattocat i have tested the above code in your site and edited. use  $(".stickylogo").attr("style", "display: inline !important"); before fadeIn() and it will work.

Comment: I added that in as well, I'm not sure if it made a difference

Comment: @gattocat this one  $(".stickylogo").attr("style", "display: inline !important");??

Comment: @gattocat Glad to help :)

Comment: I hope you don't mind me commenting again, this doesn't seem to be working on all browsers (Safari specifically), do you know why? Thanks again!